# Some IOS apps not IPv6 ready?

Tags: ios, ipv6

Apple requires that all apps in the app store to work in an all IPv6 network (no IPv4 network) according to this link

https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/

I was sniffing traffic from a few apps on the IOS and I checked to see if their APIs support IPv6 and it turns out that they don't. I checked their URLs on this site

http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php

I'm a bit puzzled about this. Aren't all apps in the Apple App store supposed to support IPv6?

One of the apps that I tested was the Textme app. Here is one of the URLs that they use within their app

https://api.textme-app.com/api/auth-token/

and by the looks of it, that domain does not support IPv6

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm on the fence on this one. The question doesn't explicitly mention programming, but knowing which environments your application might be going to run in and how to deal with them is important for software developers to know, so I decided to answer it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app needs to work in an IPv6-only environment with NAT64. That doesn't require the server to support IPv6, it just requires the app to not be bothered if the network pretends that the is reachable over IPv6-only.

Comment: On the Apple website it says "If you have a server running on the wider Internet, it is not necessary to update your server immediately. Your server will be accessible to IPv6-only devices via DNS64/NAT64." So if an iPhone is on a IPv6 only network, then some apps will not work?

Comment: All apps must work on such a network. They must be able to rely on NAT64 to make the IPv4 server reachable over IPv6.

Comment: So if my iphone has only IPv6 then I can assume I can use all the apps with no problem at all?

Comment: If your phone has only IPv6 then it's the network provider's job to provide access to IPv4 servers by offering NAT64 and DNS64

Comment: But if that was the case shouldn't http://ready.chair6.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.textme-app.com%2Fapi%2Fauth-token%2F show that it supports an AAAA record? I don't have a IPv6 network, but I will create one within the next few days to test this

Comment: Who would be providing the NAT64/DNS64 for those apps? My ISP or is it something the app dev setups?

Comment: The ISP provides NAT64/DNS64